# Como voltar o projeto a um commit específico?

Tags: git, commit

Supondo uma condição onde, eu tenho um projeto com 20 commits, e decido por razões inexplicáveis voltar alguns commits independente se quero voltar 4, 5 ou 10, supondo que a descrição de meus commits são bem claros, visualizo meus últimos commits usando o comando `$ git log`, e depois de localizado, como faço pra reverter pra um específico commit?
Quais os possíveis problemas que posso encontrar? E como saná-los?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98587/153104 Melhor resposta. Obrigado! Ajudou de verdade.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Tive esse mesmo problema, para resolver bastou utilizar o comando abaixo:

```
git reset --hard {hash-do-commit-desejado}
```

Seu `branch` vai direto para o `hash` desejado.

Answer (score 60):

Sua pergunta é muito ampla. Há muitos, muitos cenários possíveis, com várias soluções alternativas, canda uma com vantagens e desvantagens. Ainda assim, vejo três cenários importantes a considerar:

- você quer voltar seu repositório *local* a um ponto específico;
- você quer voltar um repositório *público* a um ponto específico
- você quer voltar a um ponto específico do histórico para fazer um teste, mas não quer alterar a história.

Vejamo-los, então.

## Rebobinar repositório local

Considere [este repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/brandizzi/lamecalc/commits/master). Vamos fazer umas melhoras no programa. Primeiro, clonamos o repositório localmente e o editamos.

1. Primeiro, vamos adicionar uma [shebang](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang):

   ```
   $ git diff -U1
   diff --git a/add.py b/add.py
   index 77d557c..2bb03ed 100644
   --- a/add.py
   +++ b/add.py
   @@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
   +#!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
   $
   $  git com -am "Adding shebang line"
   [master 3c1dd69] Adding shebang line
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
   ```
2. Depois, vamos tornar a saída mais explicativa:

   ```
   $ git diff -U1
   diff --git a/add.py b/add.py
   index 2bb03ed..3287cc7 100644
   --- a/add.py
   +++ b/add.py
   @@ -6,4 +6,4 @@ def add(a, b):
    a2 = int(sys.argv[2])
   -print add(a1, a2)
   +print "%d + %d = %d" % (a1, a2, add(a1, a2))
   $
   $ git com -am "Making output readable"
   [master 3cba3f9] Making output readable
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
   ```
3. Por fim, adicionamos uma saudação:

   ```
   $ git diff -U1
   diff --git a/add.py b/add.py
   index 3287cc7..676b124 100644
   --- a/add.py
   +++ b/add.py
   @@ -3,2 +3,4 @@ import sys

   +print "This is the lame calculator. Hello!"
   +
    def add(a, b):
   $
   $ git com -am "Greeting"
   [master a41916f] Greeting
    1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
   ```

Estamos prontos para enviar as alterações ao GitHub, mas decide-se que a segunda e terceira alterações são uma má ideia. Para desfazê-la, *como ela só existe no seu repositório local*, podemos usar `git reset`. Primeiro, temos este histórico:

```
$ git log --oneline -n4
a41916f Greeting
f69d7d0 Making output readable
3c1dd69 Adding shebang line
cf629bc Removing spurious line
```

Daí usamos `git reset --hard`:

```
$ git reset --hard cf629bc
HEAD is now at cf629bc Removing spurious line
```

O resultado será:

```
$ git log --oneline -n4
cf629bc Removing spurious line
e4eccaf Using better names
b0d6449 Using proper name
e0e3713 Using variables
```

Agora sim! Podemos fazer nosso *push* felizes.

## Rebobinar repositório público

Pois bem, antes de fazer nosso *push*, notamos que há commits errados já no GitHub! O commit [0b75b1](https://github.com/brandizzi/lamecalc/commit/0b75b1fbbf6858bd5fe3c46a51dda7ea424bd84b) renomeia `b` para `a2` dentro da função `add()`, onde isto não devia ser feito. O commit [e88170](https://github.com/brandizzi/lamecalc/commit/e88170571593d01a970550503b45cbac4cd40a79) é pior ainda, transformando adição em subtração sem sentido algum!

Quando vamos rebobinar repositórios públicos *quase* nunca podemos usar `git reset`. Se usássemos `git reset`, pessoa que clonasse nosso repositório teria sérios problemas para sincronizar com ele de novo. A solução no caso é `git revert`. Para isto, basta passar por parâmetro o intervalo dos commits a serem revertidos, começando do último commit a ser retirado e terminando no primeiro commit a **não** ser retirado (e88170). Isto é, você deve passar o intervalo `f187f6..e88170`:

```
$ git revert --no-edit HEAD..e88170
[master b77fd51] Revert "Using subtraction"
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[master bf5d6e0] Revert "Using better names"
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

Qual a diferença para o `git reset`? Bem, ao invés de extirpar os commits, ele adiciona novos commits desfazendo as mudanças antigas. Se você observar o último commit, ele será a versão inversa do primeiro commit revertido:

```
$ git show -U1
commit bf5d6e0a64916f9b4a40975c6e8ae519e682d37d
Author: Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <adam.brandizzi@liferay.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 6 13:01:01 2014 -0300

    Revert "Using better names"

    This reverts commit 0b75b1fbbf6858bd5fe3c46a51dda7ea424bd84b.

diff --git a/lamecalc.py b/lamecalc.py
index 3edf375..9c3a009 100644
--- a/lamecalc.py
+++ b/lamecalc.py
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ import sys
 def add(a, b):
-    return a+a2
+    return a+b


-a1 = int(sys.argv[1])
-a2 = int(sys.argv[2])
-print add(a1, a2)
+a = int(sys.argv[1])
+b = int(sys.argv[2])
+print add(a, b)
```

Agora sim! Podemos fazer o *push* das reversões. Nossos erros passados continuarão visíveis, mas não quebraremos repositórios dos nossos seguidores.

Uma coisa muito legal do `git revert` é que não precisa usá-lo só nos últimos comandos. Se você quisesse reverter somente o commit `0b75b1`, poderia fazê-lo:

```
$ git revert 0b75b1
```

Claro que poderia dar conflito, mas nesse caso era só resolvê-lo, como faz com qualquer conflito.

## Voltar ao passado para fazer um experimento

`git reset` volta o repositório atrás e *faz com que o branch atual aponte para o commit escolhido*. Nem sempre queremos isto. Por exemplo, suponha que não sabemos que commit faz com que nosso programa mostre a subtração ao invés da adição. Suspeitamos, porém, que o problema não existia na revisão `f187f6`. Neste caso, basta fazer checkout desta revisão e testar:

```
$ git co f187f6
Note: checking out 'f187f6'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at f187f65... Using variables
```

Pronto! No nosso estado atual, não há mais o commit que estranhamos:

```
$ git log --oneline -n5
f187f65 Using variables
f8f7118 Reading from parameters
e70e491 Moving to function
bbfb15d Adding operation
dd958e3 Initial commit
$
[13h13 adam@adam:~/sandbox/lamecalc] $ git branch
* (detached from f187f65)
  master
```

Testamos e constatamos que realmente o problema não existia então:

```
$ python lamecalc.py 2 2
4
```

Por outro lado, nosso branch `master` não foi alterado:

```
$ git log --oneline -n5 master
e881705 Using subtraction
0b75b1f Using better names
f187f65 Using variables
f8f7118 Reading from parameters
e70e491 Moving to function
```

Mas agora que sabemos qual é a versão que funciona, podemos voltar ao branch master com `git co master` e, então, aplicar `git revert` ao commit errado.

## O céu é o limite

Esta resposta é só a pontinha do iceberg. Há outras maneiras de retornar a um ponto - `git rebase` iterativo, checkout com `-b` etc. - cada uma com seus desafios. Rapaz, nem as que eu apresentei aqui estão completamente explicadas! Ainda assim, acho que já dá para dar uma ideia. Qualquer coisa, podemos incrementar a questão depois também, né? :)

Comment: Eu não fazia nem ideia de que se podia fazer tanta coisa assim oO ... mas enfim ... muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: parabéns para a resposta, consulto ela no mínimo uma vez por semana nas mais diversas situações ...

Answer (score 36):

Você pode dar um `git checkout <hash-do-seu-commit>`. Exemplo:

```
git checkout c8ccd1c
```

Então você voltará para o estado que estava quando fez esse *commit*.

Comment: Mas se eu retornar ao estado anterior, como no seu exemplo, `git checkout c8ccd1c`, e editar, quando der um novo `commit`, a versão acima, será sobreescrita?

Comment: @Duds, acho que o git não permitirá o commit. Ele vai te pedir para criar uma nova branch a partir deste commit se deseja realizar alguma modificação a partir daquele ponto

Comment: Acrescentaria o `git switch -c <nome-da-branch>` para copiar o estado atual do hash do commit para que você possa salvá-lo se tiver interesse. E para enviar para o repositório remoto `git push --set-upstream origin <nome-da-branch>`. Depois se for o caso você pode apagar a branch antiga `git push origin --delete <branch-antiga>`. E renomear a branch atual copiada do commit para o mesmo nome da branch antiga se quiser: `git push origin :<nome-antigo-branch> <novo-nome>`

Answer (score 1):

Acrescentando a resposta do [filipelinhares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2129/filipelinhares) (após o git checkout )

`git checkout c8ccd1c`

Acrescentaria o
`git switch -c <nome-da-branch>`
para copiar o estado do hash do commit para que você possa salvá-lo em uma nova branch, se tiver interesse.

Para enviar para o repositório remoto: `git push --set-upstream origin <nome-da-branch>`.

Depois, se for o caso, você pode apagar a branch antiga: `git push origin --delete <branch-antiga>`.

Caso queira renomear a branch atual copiada do commit para o mesmo nome da branch antiga: 
`git push origin :<nome-antigo-branch> <novo-nome>`

**Observação**: Caso seu repositório remoto não seja `origin` substitua `origin` nos comandos acima pelo nome do seu repositório remoto (`<remote>`).