# Rollback código no repositório

Tags: git, bitbucket

Boa tarde, eu tenho um repositório onde quero voltar o código a um estado anterior para fazer alguns testes em uma branch que estou atualmente e após isso, voltar a ser o que era. Como eu posso fazer isso? E estando já em uma branch com a cópia do repositório atual(que não tem o código no estado anterior), devo criar uma segunda branch e juntar ambas? Qual é a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como voltar o projeto a um commit específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19393/como-voltar-o-projeto-a-um-commit-espec%c3%adfico)

Comment: Poderia fornecer maiores detalhes das suas dúvidas? Da forma como sua descrição está disposta, de fato é uma duplicata e sua resposta está contida no link enviado pelo Dherik.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tenha uma pergunta que responda a isso, da uma olhada ai:

[Como voltar o projeto a um commit específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19393/como-voltar-o-projeto-a-um-commit-espec%C3%ADfico)