# Como retirar arquivos e pastas de um commit

Tags: git

Após fazer um commit percebi que algumas pastas e arquivos que não deveriam ir foram incluídos. Como retiro essas pastas e arquivos do commit para fazer o push?

Pensei no git reset HEAD~1 mas não sei se eu perderia as alterações feitas entre o ultimo commit que fiz e esse atual

Comment: Se fizer o reset com `--soft` as alterações são mantidas.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Revertendo o commit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479595/revertendo-o-commit)

Comment: Errei o voto, era pra ser duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19393/

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como voltar o projeto a um commit específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19393/como-voltar-o-projeto-a-um-commit-espec%c3%adfico)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui usando o --soft segundo recomendação nos comentários

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).